# Flutter, DataRow, create rows with 2 snapshot

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I get a `List<DataRow>` that can take two DataCell, one from snapshot1, and the other one from snapshot2?

This works for one snapshot,

```
  List<DataRow> _createRows(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    List<DataRow> newList =
        snapshot.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
      return new DataRow(cells: [
        DataCell(
            Text(documentSnapshot.data()['infoCoche']['idUser'].toString())),
        DataCell(
            Text(documentSnapshot.data()['infoCoche']['idUser'].toString())),
      ]);
    }).toList();

    return newList;
  }
```

what if I want 2 DataCell like this:

```
List<DataRow> _createRows(QuerySnapshot snapshot1, QuerySnapshot snapshot2) {
// Return datarow with:
  // DataCell from Snapshot1
  // DataCell from Snapshot2
}
```

how could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
List<DataRow> _createRows(QuerySnapshot snapshot1, QuerySnapshot snapshot2) {

    List<DataCell> cells1 =
            snapshot1.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
          return DataCell(
                Text(documentSnapshot.data()['infoCoche']['idUser'].toString())),
          );
        }).toList();
    List<DataCell> cells2 =
            snapshot2.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
          return DataCell(
                Text(documentSnapshot.data()['infoCoche']['idUser'].toString())),
          );
        }).toList();
    List<DataRow> dataRow = [];
    for(int i = 0; i < cells1.length; i++){
        DataRow row = DataRow(cells:[
          cells1[i],
          cells2[i],
        ]);
        dataRow.add(row);
    }
    return dataRow;
}
```